# C++ STL vector semi-constant

Tags: c++, stl, vector

I want to return an `std::vector` from a method with the following property: The receiver (the user) will be able to edit elements in the vector, but not change the vector itself (resize, remove, add, etc.)

- If I return a `std::vector<T>&`, the receiver will be able to resize it, add elements to it, etc.
- If I return a `std::vector<T> const&` (did I declare that right?), they will not be able to change the elements.
- If I return `std::vector<T>`, it will be a whole new vector, and changes to the elements wont be in the original one.

Is there any way to do this? Maybe a vetor of references, returned as const (`std::vector<T&> const`)? Is there even such a thing? And if there is, can it implicitly convert my `std::vector<T>` to it?

Comment: IMO it would be better design to give your class (for example) a function `T &at(size_t idx)` which returns a reference to just one element at a time. Or perhaps `begin()` and `end()` functions that return iterators. What you want to do, is to involve the interface of `std::vector` in the interface of your class, which ties your class to a particular implementation detail (that it stores its data in a `vector`, rather than a `deque` or `set` or whatever).

Comment: @SteveJessop That is fine, same as a `vector` doesn't hide it is a vector ;) I am trying to make a 2d array class that behaves as similar to a vector as possible. Various methods will return a "row", which is really a portion of the internal "flat" vector. I guess if I need to I can have a `it rowBegin(i)` and `it rowEnd(i)`, but I wanted also a `vector row(i)` method.

Comment: @baruch would this be of help: https://gist.github.com/3959961?

Answer (score 6):

Since you seem to have the ability to return the vector by reference, you can instead return iterators to the beginning and end of that vector. With the iterators the user can edit any of the vector members, but cannot add or remove them without having the vector itself.

You can also provide a function that provides random access with an index, possibly an overloaded `operator[]`.

Comment: The only pitfall is that the iterator may be invalidated. (Depends on the code of course.) Perhaps returning a wrapper would be better?

Comment: @ybungalobill Actually, I think that if the iterators can be invalidated, you're basically out of luck in any case. What are you going to use? Indices? Indices can be "invalidated" as well (when, say, you remove elements); it doesn't happen as often as with iterators, but the danger is still there.

Comment: @baruch I'd make `begin` and `end` functions.

Comment: I think a pair of iterators (denoting a 'range') would be fine.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want the properties of a vector, don't return a vector. Design a class that has the properties that you need. Use a vector to implement it if that's appropriate. vector is a tool, not an end in itself.

Answer (score 0):

```
// vector of pointers to elements by value
std::vector<T*>
// reference to const vector of pointers to elements
std::vector<T*> const&
// shared pointer of to const vector of pointers to elements
std::shared_ptr<std::vector<T*> const>

// vector of shared pointers to elements by value
std::vector<std::shared_ptr<T> >
// reference to const vector of shared pointers to elements
std::vector<std::shared_ptr<T> > const&
// shared pointer of to const vector of shared pointers to elements
std::shared_ptr<std::vector<std::shared_ptr<T> > const>
```